# Trouble with goroutines in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, go, goroutine

I am trying to solve this problem on [Exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/go/parallel-letter-frequency/readme):

> Write a program that counts the frequency of letters in texts using parallel computation.

Basically, I have a `FreqMap` type:

```
type FreqMap map[rune]int
```

And a `Frequency` function:

```
func Frequency(s string) FreqMap {
    m := make(FreqMap)
    for _, v := range s {
        m[v]++
    }
    return m
}
```

Exercism provides an example implementing a concurrent version using recursion, but I would like to implement my own version using a `for`  loop. I came up with the following solution, which does not work:

```
func ConcurrentFrequency(l []string) FreqMap {
    c := make(chan FreqMap)
    for i := 0; i < len(l); i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            c <- Frequency(l[i])
        }(i)
    }
    return <- c
}
```

This seems to return after only 1 iteration, `c` seems to contain the result of only 1 goroutine; I get the same result if I add a `sync.WaitGroup`.

Could you please explain what I am missing here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code seems to make only one iteration because `ConcurrentFrequency` returns the first value from the channel and thats it. I quess you want something like this:

```
func ConcurrentFrequency(l []string) chan FreqMap {
    c := make(chan FreqMap)
    go func() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(len(l))
        for _, s := range l {
            go func(s string) {
                defer wg.Done()
                c <- Frequency(s)
            }(s)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}
```

Now it returns the channel of maps, these you probaly want to combine into sigle map:

```
func main() {
    m := make(FreqMap)
    for v := range ConcurrentFrequency([]string{"foo", "bar","zoo"}) {
        for k, v := range v {
            m[k] += v
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

---

**Longer explanation that doesn't fit into comment:**

In the `for _, s := range l` loop all goroutines write into the same channel, but as that channel is not buffered, as soon as the first value is written into it, it is "full", meaning that no other values can be written into it. So only one goroutine in the loop can complete, and `wg.Done` is called only once. Thus if the source array has more than one string, the rest of the gorutines can't complete until something starts to consume values from the channel. But in your version it would be stuck in `wg.Wait` as not all goroutines are done and thus the `ConcurrentFrequency` can't return the channel to the consumer. 
In the way I wrote the `ConcurrentFrequency`, the cannel can be returned to the consumer and this (reading from the channel) enables the other `Frequency(s)` calls to write into channel.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to solve my issue indeed! Could you please explain me why we needed the first goroutine wrapping the `for` loop as well? If I remove it, there is a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` but I don't see the reason. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure how you modified the code, but I quess that it deadlocks at the wg.Wait - the consumer loop won't be reached then as the code would be stuck there. I used the WaitGroup so that the channel can be closed when all `Frequency` calls return. Thats the usual pattern when you return channel.

Comment: So if there is not a first-level goroutine closure, `wg.Wait()` timeouts the rest? My undestanding is that `wg.Done()` decrements the WaitGroup counter as soon as the goroutine closure in the`for`loop returns; then why is there a deadlock when `wg.Wait()` is placed in the `ConcurrentFrequency()` level and not in a nested goroutine? Sorry to bother you once again, just trying to understand the most of it and your feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Added explanation in the end of answer as it was too long for a comment.